# WheelPicker OnwheelChangeListener returns null onpause

Tags: view, mousewheel, android-wheel

I am using a Wheel picker called MBWheelPicker open source class that extends View and has a couple interfaces OnScrollChangeListener and OnItemSelectedListener. When  the user pauses the app and returns while entering input to the wheelpicker, the onchangelistener becomes null in the OnDraw method of the picker view and throws division by zero exception.
Here is snippet of the constructor:

```
public MBWheelPicker(Context){
this(context, null)
}

public MBWheelPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
super(context, attrs)
//here initialize TypedArray other Styleable stuff in the xml
}
```

At that point my app crashes. I can't include the whole code of the class because it's hundreds of lines of code. How can I solve this?

Both Listeners are interfaces nested in the WheelPicker class itself.

Answer (score 0):

As a custom view, it should override OnDetachWindow and onAttachWindow listeners; in my case, it lacked the latter. I added it and now it listener is not null and the nasty dividebyzero exception it caused went away.